# Is there any incident where the BJP government influenced the judiciary?

Tags: india, judiciary

There are two incidents that come to my mind:

1. The Babri Mosque trial
2. The Rafale corruption trial

Is there any evidence that suggests that the BJP government influenced the judiciary to take the judgement in their favor?

Apart from those two, is there any other instance where the BJP government influenced the judiciary?

Please supply proper references and citations in favor of your argument.

Comment: I mean the president gets to choose CJI so...

Comment: @TrystwithFreedom, No, I am not talking about the chosing of CJI. I am talking about background influence to shape the outcome of a judgement.